# How Outlook shows the PaperClip icon for any attachment other than embedded images?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, email-attachments

For my use case, I need to find out if a mail item in outlook has any embedded image as an attachment. I am working on Outlook 2013+ version. It is my understanding that for all other embedded attachments, they can only be added in Rich Text format and Outlook marks them as attachment (Marked as PaperClip icon). But if the mail contains only a embedded image in HTML format then the PaperClip icon does not appear. Please feel free me to point me if I am wrong with this observation.

My question however is, how is outlook itself deciding and showing the paperclip icon? I used Outlook Spy but the PR_HasAttach is set to true for these mails. I have also read other solutions where people have pointed out that you can try to find  tag in the HTML Mail body which mostly works. But has any body ever wondered about the PaperClip icon?

I am having this doubt because when I apply the DASL filter urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment = true, such mails are filtered out by the query. Same thing happens if you use has attachments filter in outlook itself. But if I select the same mail item, and try to explore this property either by code or by Outlook Spy, it comes as true. That is why I am thinking that it might have to do with the icon Or atleast If I can find the property which sets the icon.

**Edit 1:**
When I use the following code it does not work for embedded or hidden attachments. For others it works.

```
IEnumerator eNum = listOfSearchedOutlookItems.GetEnumerator();
while (eNum.MoveNext())
{
      Outlook.MailItem mailItem;
      try
      {
          mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)eNum.Current;
          bool b = mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B");
       }
       catch
       {
          continue;
       }
  }
```

However strangely the following works for all the cases (As many as I have tested). So in a way this problem is solved thanks to Dmitry's answer. But still wondering why is the previous one not working.

```
Outlook.Table table = MyFolder.GetTable(SomeFilterIfNeeded);
table.Columns.RemoveAll();
table.Columns.Add(@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B");

while (!table.EndOfTable)
{
     Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow();
     bool b = (bool)nextRow[@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B"];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the paperclip icon, Outlook sets `SmartNoAttach` named MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B`).

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. This works. So can we use this property and the mailItem.Attachments.Count together to determine if the email has any embedded image attachment or do you see any issue in that?

Comment: Ok, so I tried this approach from my C# code but it does not work. From outlook spy I can see that property is being set properly but when I am trying to access from code, it is referring to some other property. I am sure about this since changing the value of that property from code does not affect the PaperClip icon, but it certainly changes when done from OutlookSpy.

Comment: Added the code in edit. Although the problem is solved, please do help if you can figure out what is wrong in the first approach as it will be helpful for me.

Comment: I am confused - what exactly does not work? Are you saying you can see the property changed, but PropertyAccessor.GetProperty returns a wrong value?

Comment: I mean If there is a embedded image or hidden attachment then PropertyAccesssor.GetProperty is returning a wrong value.Using SetProperty also changes something but not the correct Mapi Property. But using Outlook.Table works fine for this case.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right item? Can you be more specific? Does GetProperty return false but the con is still shown? Make sure you handle exceptions -if the property is nto set at all, you will get back an exception rather than a value.

Comment: Sorry if I am confusing you. If my understanding is correct then, GetProperty should return false if the icon is present and true if the icon is not present.  However, for embedded images the icon is not present in Outlook mail but GetProperty returns false. And for hidden attachments, the icon is present but GetProperty returns true. Every thing is in try catch but they are returning values and no exception is being thrown. I am sure about the property since I am using the same in Outlook.Table and getting appropriate values.